# How can I successfully rename a repository without having multiple errors after?

Tags: github, github-pages

I renamed a repository and tried to follow the steps on the help pages, but as you can see by the images the old name is still active apparently and is causing me errors:

1. rename the url
2. add the new url that already exists apparently
3. try to push changes but "is not found"

How can it give me the status of "not found" and already exist" for the same repository with the same URL?

Would appreciate if someone can shed some light on the matter :

```
 Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   _casestudies/case-one.html

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

HP@carlas MINGW64 ~/Documents/Wed Development/portfolio (gh-pages)
$ git add .

HP@carlas MINGW64 ~/Documents/Wed Development/portfolio (gh-pages)
$ git remote -v
github  https://carlashub.github.io/carlashub/ (fetch)
github  https://carlashub.github.io/carlashub/ (push)
origin  https://carlashub.github.io/carla/ (fetch)
origin  https://carlashub.github.io/carla/ (push)

HP@carlas MINGW64 ~/Documents/Wed Development/portfolio (gh-pages)
$ git commit -m "removed broken link"
[gh-pages 19bf5a1] removed broken link
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

 ~/Documents/Wed Development/portfolio (gh-pages)
$ git push -u origin gh-pages
fatal: repository 'https://carlashub.github.io/carla/' not found

HP@carlas MINGW64 ~/Documents/Wed Development/portfolio (gh-pages)
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/CarlasHub/carla.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.

HP@carlas MINGW64 ~/Documents/Wed Development/portfolio (gh-pages)
$ git push -u origin gh-pages
fatal: repository 'https://carlashub.github.io/carla/' not found
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your commands and error messages as _text_, not a screenshot.

Comment: Those URLs don't look like valid GitHub repository URLs. They look like URLs where GitHub Pages get published. What are you trying to do?

Comment: what is the difference between "GitHub repository URLs" and "URL's where Github pages are published "?  Soon as i get to my laptop again i will edit the post thanks

Comment: A GitHub repository URL is something you'd `git clone` / `fetch` / `pull` from or `git push` to. A URL where GitHub Pages are published is where specially named and formatted repositories are published for viewing through a regular web browser. You wouldn't ever push to a GitHub Pages URL; you'd push to the corresponding repository and GitHub Pages would automatically build and publish to the GitHub Pages site.

Comment: Carla, what were you trying to do when you changed your repository's URL?

Comment: I was trying to change the URL precisely, just that

Comment: But for what purpose? Were you trying to change the URL in and of itself, or were you trying to accomplish some goal by changing it?

Comment: I just wanted the url to be different from what is was that was my goal rename simply...any idea what is happening and what i can do to fix the this error ?

Comment: I think you may still be confused between the URL where a GitHub Pages site would go and the URL you need to push your repository to. Are you trying to change the URL that a visitor would go to if they wanted to see your site?

Comment: Thanks for your help, i just posted the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the URL misunderstanding.

As Chris mentioned above I was confusing the **page URL** with the **repository URL** and thanks for pointing that out. I guess the main issue is the similar nomenclature of both, something I will avoid in the future.

I was trying to push to GitHub Pages URL:

```
https://carlashub.github.io/carla/
```

And I needed to push to the  GitHub repository at this URL instead:

```
https://github.com/CarlasHub/carla
```

I fixed this by running this command:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/CarlasHub/carla
```

After, running the push again:

```
git push -u origin gh-pages
```

Now everything works.

Comment: Good job taking my comments, doing more research, and figuring this out. And thank you for adding an answer on your own question; this will help other users in the future if they have similar confusion.